# reading multidimensional arrays using for each in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array in the following format:

```
0 => 
array (size=4)
  'timestamp' => string '1/2/2014 7:59' (length=13)
  'phase1' => string '16264' (length=5)
  'phase2' => string '16671' (length=5)
  'phase3' => string '7146' (length=4)


1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'timestamp' => string '2/2/2014 7:59' (length=13)
      'phase1' => string '16310' (length=5)
      'phase2' => string '16105' (length=5)
      'phase3' => string '7211' (length=4)
```

I want to create another array within another item to the array that will add the values of `phase1`, `phase2` and `phase3`

Something like this.

```
$total_value[$i]['total'] = $csv_file[$i]['phase1'] + $csv_file[$i]['phase2'] + $csv_file[$i]['phase3'];
```

I tried using a `for` loop but it doesn't work:

```
for($i = 0; i < $size_of_array; $i++ ) {
            $total_value[$i]['total'] = $csv_file[$i]['phase1'] + $csv_file[$i]['phase2'] + $csv_file[$i]['phase3']; 

        }
```

Comment: you're adding everytime the `phase1`cell... copy pasted and forgetted to change the cellname ?

Comment: Sorry, wrote the code but copypasted the variables. let me edit it

Comment: Ok, and show how you get the content of the $size_of_array variable. It can be the problem.

Comment: `i < $size_of_array` was that a mistake too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach($csv_file as $key => $values) {
    $total_value[$key]['total'] = $values['phase1'] + $values['phase2'];
    //$total_value[$key] = $values['phase1'] + $values['phase2'];
}
```

I would use the commented line so I just had a single-dimension (easier to work with):

Comment: Thanks that worked. I have been trying to avoid foreach as much as possible. I guess its time to learn it

Comment: `foreach` is indispensable, especially when working with arrays and objects.

Answer (score 3):

Please see how you can deal with objects using foreach
try using foreach by referring

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php